# Is there an easy way to revoke all AWS Lake Formation permissions at once for a user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lake-formation

I have a data lake with more than 2000 permissions that i want to revoke for some users and restart to granting again.

By the console the revoke is done one by one and it will take much time. Is there a way to revoke all permissions at once for a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done programmatically:

1. Call ListPermissions API to get all the granted permissions.
2. Filter permissions granted to those users.
3. Call BatchRevokePermissions API to revoke all permissions for those users.